# I can't see my data in my mongodb databse

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

this is the first time I'm using MongoDB and when I connect my MongoDB database by SSH connection to Studio 3T I can see the database and the collection: Hre he is (I'm hosting the website on a server under centos 8)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA5B6.png)

The website work, I can signup, signing, logout, etc but I can't see the users in my user's collection : [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ2Ge.png)

I'm using a source of a website in nodejs and the database already have users etc and I just would like to clear it and to add the rank admin on my user to have access to the admin panel.

I don't understand why those collections are empty.

EDIT : when I try to connect my mongodb database to studio 3t by URI I have this error :

```
connection failed.

SERVER [45.9.188.221:27017] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketOpenException): Exception opening socket
|____/ Socket error: Connection refused: connect

Details:
Timed out after 5000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=45.9.188.221:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
```

Help, please

Comment: please share to code where you defined the connection (without the actual keys)

Comment: how it should look like?

Comment: depends on the service
take a look here
https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/connect-to-mongodb-atlas/

Comment: I connected my db to studio 3T via the SSH connection option https://i.gyazo.com/073cd80f4a75ec6cc7dca8f0d386d2b6.png

Comment: 1- Are you using authentication? If so make sure you have appropriate privileges to query on that collection.
2- You should use another tool (mongo shell, robo 3t or your node.js driver) if you are in doubt  to compare what it should be and studio 3t cannot priovide this information.

Comment: im not using authentification